# How to perform batch inserts into SQLite using JavaScript ? I am using the phonegap+sencha framework

Tags: javascript, performance, sqlite, cordova, sencha-touch

I am retrieving 4 mb of JSON data from the server and inserting it into the local database on an android phone.

Does sencha support this feature ?

Sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For that amount of data, I would suggest taking a look at [brodysoft's SQLite Plugin](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) for Cordova. You'll be able to create databases as large as the device has available storage. Once you get that in place, you can set up `Ext.data.Store` objects as needed where the data will be exposed in the UI. Review `Ext.data.reader.Reader` - you'll probably want to extend that to access specific tables in the SQLite database.